# Integer dot product using SSE/AVX?

Tags: c++, vectorization, sse, simd, avx

I am looking at the intel intrinsic guide:

https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/

and whilst they have `_mm_dp_ps` and `_mm_dp_pd` for calculating the dot product for floats and doubles I cannot see anything for calculating the integer dot product.

I have two `unsigned int[8]` arrays and I would like to:

(a[0] x b[0]) + (a[1] * b[1])....... + (a[num_elements_in_array-1] * b[num_elements_in_array-1])

(in batches of four) and sum the products?

Comment: Why does this question keep changing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every time someone does this:

```
temp_1 = _mm_set_epi32(x[j], x[j+1], x[j+2], x[j+3]);
```

.. a puppy dies.

Use one of these:

```
temp_1 = _mm_load_si128(x);  // if aligned
temp_1 = _mm_loadu_si128(x); // if not aligned
```

Cast `x` as necessary.

There is no integer version of `_mm_dp_ps`. But you can do what you were about to do: multiply 4 by 4 integers, accumulate the sum of the products.

So something like this (not tested, doesn't compile)

```
while(j < num_elements_in_array){
    //Load the 4 values from x
    temp_1 = _mm_load_si128(x + j); // add cast
    //Load the 4 values from y
    temp_2 = _mm_load_si128(y + j); // add cast
    j += 4;
    //Multiply x[0] and y[0], x[1] and y[1] etc
    temp_products = _mm_mullo_epi32(temp_1, temp_2);
    //Sum temp_sum
    temp_sum = _mm_add_epi32(temp_sum, temp_products);
}
// take horizontal sum of temp_sum
temp_sum = _mm_add_epi32(temp_sum, _mm_srli_si128(temp_sum, 8));
temp_sum= _mm_add_epi32(temp_sum, _mm_srli_si128(temp_sum, 4));
sum = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(temp_sum);
```

As discussed in the comments and chat, that reorders the sums in such a way as to minimize the number of horizontal sums required, by doing most sums vertically.

Comment: I dont mean to scare you by asking this- I know what alignment is generally, but i do not know if I require it for this?

Comment: @user997112 what do you mean?

Comment: @harold I do not know whether I require aligned/unaligned and when I need either generally. Also, once I get the result of the sum from _mm_add_epi32, it looks like you're returning it to a __m128i? Wouldn't I wish to return this back to a normal int to increment sum?

Comment: @user997112 do the horizontal sum at the end, outside the loop. There's no reason to do it sooner, and it's slower than a regular (vertical) sum. Things have to be aligned if you're going to blindly access them with aligned loads or stores.

Comment: @harold I am thinking generally- if I had arrays of size 20, i'd need 5 loop iterations and therefore on each loop iteration I would have to increment sum using normal int addition?

Comment: I understand now why you recommended waiting until the end to do the sum, but I need to assume that I may have more than 4 loop iterations and do the increment inside the loop.... how would I sum temp_products and return a normal int?

Comment: @user997112 why would you have to do it inside the loop?

Comment: Lets say my two arrays are 100 elements each, this means loading 4 integers and multiplying 4 integer for each 25 loop iterations. Therefore we will be summing the results of the multiplications 25 times, one for each loop? It also looks like I cannot use _mm_load_si128 because it requires __128i* type

Comment: @user997112 Just cast that pointer. And yes as you say, you will then do 25 sums (and some more at the end to merge the 4 partial sums).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51063/discussion-between-user997112-and-harold)